# Crear Ventana con Barra de menu Python Pyqt5

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5

Estoy creando una ventana la cual tenga una barra menú, pero cuando corro el programa con sólo una de las opciones en la barra de menú aparece este error:

> mainMenu = self.menuBar()
>
> AttributeError: 'VentanaC' object has no attribute 'menuBar'

El código es el siguiente:

```
class VentanaC(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(VentanaC, self).__init__()
        
        self.title = "Observaciones - INICM"
        self.top = 200
        self.left = 500
        self.width = 680
        self.height = 480
        self.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon("icono.png"))
        self.setWindowTitle(self.title)
        self.setGeometry(self.left, self.top, self.width, self.height)

        self.CreateMenu()

    def CreateMenu(self):

        mainMenu = self.menuBar()
        fileMenu = mainMenu.addMenu('File')
         

if __name__ == '__main__':
   
    aplicacion = QApplication(sys.argv)

    ventana = VentanaC()
    ventana.show()

    sys.exit(aplicacion.exec_())
```

No sé por que sucede esto. Otra pregunta que me surge es si el error se presenta por el tipo de ventana, ya que la puse como QDialog, la verdad aún no entiendo muy bien cuando debe ser QDialog, Qwidgets, etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En ningún momento has añadido el `QMenuBar`.

En ventanas más completas como `QMainWindow` las traen por defecto, una menubar y una statusbar, y algunos controles más. Pero en otros tipos de ventanas no es así.

1: La manera más sencilla de solucionarlo es convertir tu ventana en una `QMainWindow`

2: Una manera alternativa sería añadir explicitamente el nuevo elemento (En este caso una QMenuBar) a tu ventana QDialog. Realmente no sé si será posible, pero yo haría algo así.

```
def CreateMenu(self):
    mainMenu = QMenuBar(self)
    self.layout().setMenuBar(mainMenu)
    fileMenu = mainMenu.addMenu('File')
```

Nota: No lo he testeado (No puedo ahora, desde mi telefono) pero debería funcionar.

**Actualizacion tras los comentarios:**
Puedes crear una ventana pasandole parametros, en este caso lo llamo ejemplo.

```
class VentanaPrincipal(QMainWindow):
    ventanac = QDialog(ejemplo=self)  # Se pasa una referencia de la clase VentanaPrincipal (self) a la ventanaC

class VentanaC(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None, ejemplo):
        self.ventanaprincipal = ejemplo  # Se añade la referencia a esta clase
```

Con ese código ahora puedes, desde cualquier lado de tu QDialog, pedirle cosas a la ventana principal, ya que has creado una referencia dentro de la clase. Por ejemplo:

```
self.ventanaprincipal.menuBar()
self.ventanaprincipal.statusBar.showMessage("ejemplo")
```

Comment: Hola, pues lo probe de la segunda opcion dejando la ventana como QDialog pero no me funciona, me aparece:

Comment: ¿Qué aparece? no entiendo

Comment: Discupa no se por que no aparecio lo demas del comentario, lo que aparecio fue esto:

self.layout().setMenuBar(mainMenu)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'setMenuBar'

Comment: Mi problema con lo de las clases es que quiero meter este codigo en uno que es el principal de una app, cuando se presiona un boton en la app Principal, se despliega este codigo que puse aqui, entonces es posible dejar el codigo de la Ventana QMenuBar y llamarlo desde el codigo principal cuando se presione el Boton?

Comment: Puedes hacer que una QMainWindow abra otra QMainWindow sin problema. No es necesario que las ventanas "secundarias" sean QDialog. Los QDialog se usan principalmente para devolver un valor a la ventana principal. (El error que te da es porque tu QDialog no tiene un layout, tendrías que añadirlo). En `Qt` muchos pasos pueden saltarse, pero dan resultados inesperados, cuidado con eso. Respecto a tu pregunta, sí, es posible y muy sencillo, mira mi codigo actualizado.

Comment: Aaaa okey okey entiendo, Muchas gracias amig@ :D